# How to debug a C++ segfault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Apparently since its a segfault the C++ compiler won't output anything? I'm having some trouble with some C++ code I wrote. I'm a novice and I've been looking for this segfault for some time now... I can't figure it out.

My best guess is it is somewhere in the Deck() constructor, can anyone give me a hand?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Follow up: In the future, does anyone have any good methods of debugging segfaults?

Deck.cpp

```
#include "Deck.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::ostream;
using std::vector;

const string Deck::RANKS[13] = {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};
const string Deck::SUITS[4] = {"H","D","C","S"};
string cards[52];
int card = 0;


Deck::Deck() : size(0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            cards[size] = RANKS[i] + SUITS[j];
            size++;
        }
    }

    shuffle();
}

Deck::~Deck() {}

void Deck::shuffle()
{
    size = MAX_SIZE;
    std::random_shuffle(&cards[0], &cards[MAX_SIZE-1]);
}

string Deck::getCard()
{
    card++;
    return cards[card-1];
}
```

Deck.h

```
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H


#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::ostream;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

class Deck
{
private:
    static const int MAX_SIZE = 52;
    static const string RANKS[13];
    static const string SUITS[4];
    static const string DECK[52];

    int size;


public:
    Deck();
    ~Deck();
    void shuffle();
    string getCard();
    int getDeckSize() const {return size;}
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Deck&);
};

#endif
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Deck.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{


   int pairs = 0;

   for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
   {
       cout << "yep";

       Deck deck;
       cout << "awooga";

       deck.shuffle();
       cout << "hai";

       string cards[2];

       cards[0] = deck.getCard();
       cards[1] = deck.getCard();

       for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
       {
           string tempCard = deck.getCard();
           if(cards[0].compare(tempCard) == 0 || cards[1].compare(tempCard) == 0)
           {
              pairs++;     
           }
       }
   }


   cout << pairs;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger? That usually helps quite a bit... The presence of the output statements indicates you're relying on them to tell you how far your code executed. Learn to use your debugger.

Comment: *Debugging Assistance Please* --- Use GDB ...

Comment: Useful fact of the day: Debuggers like gdb can tell you the exact spot + backtrace where the segfault occurred and tools like valgrind can sometimes tell you even more. You should learn how to use them.

Comment: _"does anyone have any good methods of debugging segfaults?"_ Yes, use your debugger. Don't do it in the future — do it _now_!

Comment: If you move `string deck[52];` and `int card;` from your `.cpp` file into your header file and initialize `card = 0;` in `Deck`'s constructor then the segmentation fault will not occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `getCard` has side effects, increasing the value of `card` every time you call it. As soon as you call it more than 52 times, your program may crash. Note that `card` is a global variable and doesn't reset to zero whenever you create a new deck.

I also noticed that your call to `random_shuffle` has an off-by-one error. The end iterator needs to be one beyond the actual end of your container, not pointing *at* the end (so it's a half-open range).

Finally for debugging segmentation faults in general, enable core dumps on your system and use gdb to attach the core to your binary. That will sometimes give you a good clue where to start.

Comment: Thanks for the all the responses! Looking into getting these debuggers now. The getCard function makes sense how the Card can go over 52. However, I create a new deck after every 7 calls of getCard (2 outside the loop and 5 in the inner loop). Does this not reset the variable counter that getCard is using?

Comment: Your card variable is in the global namespace in the Deck.cpp file. Oops.

Comment: Ah, so the real issue is where that variable is declared. Thanks!